# How to get higher 20 bits from 64-bit integer?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, integer, bit

I am using 64-bit Mac OS X, I have an NSUInteger(or uint64, it does not matter on my system).

How to get higher 20 bits of NSUInteger and store it in another NSUInteger?

You may answer how to do that in C, C++, or Objective-C.

P.S. Please, don't tell me to modify all the code and use bit-fields instead.

P.P.S. I guess I have to use bit mask and shifting?

Comment: Don't you simply want `i >> 44`? Or `(i >> 44) & 0xFFFFF` if NSUInteger can be larger than 64.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For uint64_t, you can simply use

```
i >> 44
```

For signed types or types that might be larger than 64-bits, you'll also need to mask away the higher bits.

```
(i >> 44) & 0xFFFFF
```

---

A smaller-scale example,

```
4 bits starting at pos 2 of 8.

  7   6   5   4   3   2   1   0
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| ? | ? |       j       | ? | ? |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

                             >> 2

+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| * | * | ? | ? |       j       |   * = 0 if unsigned or original bit7 if signed.
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+ 

                   & ( 2**4 - 1 )

+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |       j       |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: +1 - Nice ASCII artwork, shows the bit manipulation is picture form.

Answer (score 0):

```
uint64 original = ...;
uint64 another = ((0xFFFFF00000000000 & original) >> 44);
```

First and with bit mask then move right 44 bits.

Comment: If you shift first and then mask it, your're less likely to make a mistake typing the constant.

Comment: Masking first will also fail for signed types.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't aware of a problem with shifting first for signed numbers. Is that an implementation dependent feature? It doesn't seem to matter much if you shift before or after for signed or unsigned for my implementation:

```
int main()
{
  uint64_t a = std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max();
  int64_t  b = std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::max();
  uint64_t c = std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max();
  int64_t  d = std::numeric_limits<int64_t>::max();

  a = (0xFFFFF00000000000 & a) >> 44;
  b = (0xFFFFF00000000000 & b) >> 44;
  c = 0xFFFFF & (c >> 44);
  d = 0xFFFFF & (d >> 44);
  cout << "a = " << a << "; c = " << c << "; a?=c = " << (a==c) << endl;
  cout << "b = " << b << "; d = " << b << "; b?=d = " << (b==d) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

This produces:

```
a = 1048575; c = 1048575; a?=c = 1
b = 524287; d = 524287; b?=d = 1

$ c++ --version
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
```